# No aparecen los datos en el DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Tengo un problema, al listar en el datagridview no me aparecen los datos que guardé en un arrayList. Estoy aprendiendo c# , por mi influencia en java llego a confundir ciertos aspectos por eso sospecho que estoy cometiendo errores en lógica (no me aparecen errores al compilar). A continuación lo comparto, trabajo con 3 capas y en SharpDevelop.

CapaLogica

```
public class Persona
    {
    
        private int dni;
        private string nombre;
        
        public int Dni {
            get { return dni; }
            set { dni = value; }
        }

        public string Nombre {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }
        
        }
```

CapaDatos

```
public class listaPersonas
    {
        
        private static ArrayList lista= new ArrayList();
        
        
        public static void adicionar(Object obj) {
            
            lista.Add(obj);
        }
        
        public static ArrayList consultar() {
            return lista;
        }
```

CapaCliente

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        
        
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            int dni= Convert.ToInt16(txtDni.Text);
            string nombre= txtNombre.Text;
            
            Persona obj = new Persona();
            obj.Dni=dni;
            obj.Nombre=nombre;
            
            listaPersonas.adicionar(obj);
        }
        
        void ListarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgv.DataSource=listaPersona.consultar();
        }
        
        
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica estaba bien, no me aparecian los datos en DataGrid por que no habia asignado que la columna nombre se referia a nombre y la columna dni se referia a dni.

Igualmente se aceptan otras sugerencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que suelo hacer es usar un `BindingList<T>` en lugar de una `Lista/ArrayList`,
y lo bindeo al `dataSource` del `DataGrid` mediante un `BindingSource`.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<Persona> personas;
    BindingSource dSource;
    public Form1()
    {
        this.personas = new BindingList<Persona>();
        this.dSource = new BindingSource(personas,null);
        InitializeComponent();
        dgv.DataSource = dSource;
    }
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int dni = Convert.ToInt16(txtDni.Text);
        string nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        Persona obj = new Persona();
        obj.Dni = dni;
        obj.Nombre = nombre;
        personas.Add(obj); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, investigaré acerca de los BindingList.